# Why does the filter apply to multiple columns?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have two columns that are identical (see picture below "sec Diag" and "2ndary"). I want to filter "sec diag", but not have that apply to "2ndary." as you can see from the picture below i have a different filter for each column. But when i filter "sec diag" it applies to "2ndary" also.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there are cases where  "sec Diag" and "2ndary" are not equal to each other? I'm wondering if the filters are actually working correctly, but the dataset has no rows where the two columns have differing values.

Comment: IF the two columns are identical and part of the same table, then filtering one will *filter the other column as well*. Filters remove all rows from the *table* that fail the filter criterion.